# Shipping credit memo applies taxes twice

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo, shipping-tax

When I create a new credit memo for shipping costs the shipping taxes are calculated twice:

[image]

Notice: Before, I created a credit memo for the product price to have a better overview what happens with the shipping refund.

4,95 are the shipping costs (incl. taxes). The problem is, that magento adds the taxes (0,79) again.

Here is a full example:

[image]

This is an offline example, but when I try to refund payments made with RatePay or PayPal, they receive a refund request 0,79€ higher than the price paid before.

Has anybody experienced something like that before and has an idea what is happening here? Where should I start to look for the root of this problem? Maybe I can fix the problem in a submodule.

The price calculation works anywhere else correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem while I tested each community and local module separated.

In a custom module we create custom invoice pdfs and here is the problem:

`foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
  $order = $invoice->getOrder();
  $order->setShippingAmount( ($order->getShippingAmount() + 
                              $order->getShippingTaxAmount()) );
}`

The order is saved somehow after the pdf has been generated and the result is a wrong shipping cost amount.